# Parameterizing a circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I wanted to parameterize $S = \{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, 0 \leq z \leq 1\}$.

Would this parameterization be given by $G(u,v) = (u \cos(v), u \sin(v), u)$ for $0 \leq u \leq 1$ and $0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$?

The confusion I am having is with regards to $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. If this were simply one, it would be parameterizing the unit circle, but being $\leq 1$ throws me off here.

Any help appreciated.

Following suggestions, I assume this would then be $G(u,v, z) = (u \cos(v), u \sin(v), z)$ for $0 \leq u \leq 1$ and $0 \leq v \leq 2\pi, 0 \leq z \leq 1$

Comment: You should use another variable to parameterize $z$.

Comment: Why should I use another parameter?

Comment: The way you have it written right now, you cannot get, say, the point $(1,0,0)$, which lies on the cylinder of radius $1$ and the plane $z=0$ because it would require $u=1$ and $u=0$. This is a 3-dimensional region, so 3 parameters will be required.

Comment: Hmm. Then suppose I am computing the flux of a vector field through this surface, wouldn't this result in a triple integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parameterize the solid $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have to have 3 parameters. In your current parameterization, your $z$ coordinate depends also on the radius of the circle. This would cause it have a cone-like shape. If you wanted to parameterize the solid it would be something like:

$g(u,v,z) = (u\cos{v},u\sin{v},z)$ where $0\leq z\leq1$ and $u,v$ have the same restrictions.

If you wanted to parameterize only the surface of the cylinder, than, we can parameterize in 2 variables with the parameterization:

$g(u,v) = (\cos{v},\sin{v},u)$ where $v$ has the usual restriction and $u$ acts as the $z$-coordinate so its restriction is similar to $z$, namely: $0\leq u\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $S$ is a solid cylinder. The cylindrical part of the bounding surface is
$$
\{x^2 + y^2 = 1, 0 \le z \le 1\}.
$$
You can parameterize that with two parameters - just omit the $u$ in the first part of your proposed solution.